# Actionscript 3.0 mechanics: digging ExternalInterface and _evalJS

Tags: actionscript, eval

Here is decompiled sources of ExternalInterface:

http://pastebin.com/B8c7keWL

_evalJS is empty, probably extended later in the runtime.

Here is where the magic happens:

`loc5 = _evalJS(loc1);`

_evalJS is keeping context of eval function provided.

So for example i have called this code in Actionscript:

```
ExternalInterface.call('MyObject.innerObject.func',params);
```

And it `.func` will still know it's initial context.

Anyone knows how it's working?

Any guru here? :)

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s some internal thing of the Flash Player itself, and not part (or expressible in) of the ActionScript language.